# Recursive Deduction of array

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, database

Hi I have this array values

```
#    amount   deduction
[0]   50        10
[1]   160       20
[2]   300       20
```

I want to have a recursive deduction of these arrays until data is zero, and then if the first amount of the array is zero(0) the deduction will add to the next data, until all amount will be zero (0). **Sample Calculation below**

```
[0]          [1]          [2]
50  - 10     160 - 20     300 - 20
40  - 10     140 - 20     280 - 20
30  - 10     120 - 20     260 - 20
20  - 10     100 - 20     240 - 20
10  - 10      80 - 20     220 - 20
 0            60 - 30     200 - 20
              30 - 30     180 - 20
              0           160 - 50
                          110 - 50
                           60 - 50
                           10 - 50
                           0
```

I don't know how to do it but this is my code so far.

```
foreach($data as $det)
{
   $_monthly_payment = $det->deduction;
   $_beginning_balance = $det->amount;
   $i = 0;

   do{
     $_new_balance = (($i + 1) == 1) ? $_beginning_balance : $_ending_balance;
     $_toward_principal      = $_monthly_payment;
     $_ending_balance        = $_new_balance - $_toward_principal;

     <tr>
        <td><?php echo number_format($_monthly_payment,2); ?></td>
        <td>$<?php echo number_format($_new_balance,2); ?> </td>
        <td>$<?php echo number_format($_toward_principal,2); ?> </td>
        <td>$<?php echo number_format($_ending_balance,2); ?> </td>
     </tr>
   }
   while( $i <= $_ending_balance );
}
```

Please don't judge me guys, I just need this so badly. Thank you guys.

**Updated**
Result of my `var_dump`

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#1334 (1) { 
    ["items":protected]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#1341 (26) { 
            ["id"]=> int(130) ["account_name"]=> string(3) "QWE" ["amount"]=> float(50) ["deduction"]=> float(10) ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2023-01-09 15:49:59" } 
        [1]=> object(stdClass)#1345 (26) { 
            ["id"]=> int(131) ["account_name"]=> string(3) "ABC" ["amount"]=> float(160) ["deduction"]=> float(20) ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2023-01-09 15:49:59" } 
        [2]=> object(stdClass)#1326 (26) { 
            ["id"]=> int(132) ["account_name"]=> string(3) "XYZ" ["amount"]=> float(300) ["deduction"]=> float(20) ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2023-01-09 15:49:59" } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `foreach($data $det)` Not valid PHP

Comment: Please show your input array `$data` as the output from a `export_var($data)` just so we are sure of its layout

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry I updated it, I mistype it

Comment: _"the deduction will add to the next data"_ - so when we are done with processing the first record out of your input array, that deduction gets added to the deduction to subtract from the second element from then on? Can we assume that your input data will always be such, that there this _is_ an amount to process in the second one, at this point? If not - then what if the deduction of the second record had been 100 to begin with? Then there would be no amount left at the point the first record's amount reaches zero - how to proceed in that case then?

Comment: @CBroe Yes you can assume it that the data will always be such. And yes it will continue to the next data and will still add the 100 to  the next deduction.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the result of my ```var_dump```

Comment: I actually asked for a `VAR_EXPORT()` except i spelt it wrong :)

Comment: Cobbled something together, that should get the output you want - https://3v4l.org/0mSdf  (rendered result: https://jsfiddle.net/vcwyk98p/) Be aware that this manipulates the input array, so if you still need the original data afterwards - clone it first.

Comment: @CBroe I know it is so late already but I hope I can get a response again. But how about if the  first data is much longer than the second data? Example the [0] = 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer big help of @CBroe. This will continue the deduction if the first data of the array is zero(0).

```
<?php

$data = [
    ['amount' => 50, 'deduction' => 10],
    ['amount' => 160, 'deduction' => 20],
    ['amount' => 300, 'deduction' => 20],
];

$continue = true;

echo '<table>';
while($continue) {
    $continue = max(array_column($data, 'amount')) > 0;
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i=0; $i<count($data); ++$i) {
        echo '<td>';
        echo !isset($data[$i]['done']) ? max($data[$i]['amount'], 0) : '';
        if($data[$i]['amount'] <= 0 && !isset($data[$i]['done'])) {
            $data[$i]['done'] = true;
            if(isset($data[$i+1])) {
                $data[$i+1]['deduction'] += $data[$i]['deduction'];
            }
        }
        echo !isset($data[$i]['done']) ? ' - '.$data[$i]['deduction'] : '';
        echo '</td>';
        
        $data[$i]['amount'] -= $data[$i]['deduction'];
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    
} 
echo '</table>';
```